Oracle - Log the static SQL script which produced error inside PL\SQL procedure, into a table
I have some PL\SQL Procedures that execute static DML statements and use some pl\sql variables
in where clause.
For example:
 procedure execute_insert is 

         l_parameter varchar2(100);

    begin

         l_parameter := '5';
    
         Insert into Destination_Table(id)
         select id
           from Source_Table st
         where 1=1
           and st.id = l_parameter;
    
 exception
        when others then
             (error logging)

 end execute_insert;

I want to be able to write this sql statement in case it produces error into a log table .
I found this https://tonyhasler.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/identifying-the-sql_id-of-static-sql-in-plsql-blocks/?unapproved=8391&moderation-hash=1cfb98260e508b941a539d746d98144f#respond
Which actually uses this package:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SQL_UTIL as 
   FUNCTION GET_LAST_SQLTEXT RETURN CLOB;
end SQL_UTIL;

/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SQL_UTIL
AS
   FUNCTION GET_LAST_SQLTEXT
      RETURN CLOB
   IS
      l_sql_text   CLOB;
   BEGIN
      SELECT   sql_fulltext
        INTO   l_sql_text
        FROM      v$sql sq
               JOIN
                  v$session se
               ON     sq.sql_id = se.prev_sql_id
                  AND se.prev_child_number = sq.child_number
                  AND sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID');

      RETURN l_sql_text;
   END;
END SQL_UTIL;
/

And use it like this:
DECLARE
   x   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   select   1 INTO x FROM dual;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sql_util.get_last_sqltext);
END;

But this solution doesn't work for my case because it won't print the value of pl\sql variable - For example in below PL\SQL Block:
   DECLARE
       x   VARCHAR2(10);
       y   VARCHAR2(50) := '5';
    BEGIN
       select  y INTO x FROM dual;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sql_util.get_last_sqltext);
    END;

It will print:
SELECT :B1 FROM DUAL

And i want to get:
SELECT 5 FROM DUAL 

Is there any alternative to achieve this without the use of dynamic sql?
And i also don't want to put a comment inside statement in order to trace it.
Thank you in advance.

before you write any custom code, check out this well received open source utility, simply called, logger https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger

You won't be able to get SELECT 5 FROM DUAL because that isn't the text of your SQL cursor. In PL/SQL, y is a local variable. When used in a SQL statement embedded in PL/SQL (your implicit cursor), it functions as a bind variable. The actual SQL cursor is parsed with the place-holder: SELECT :B1 FROM DUAL. If this were not the case, it would have to reparse and create a new cursor for every value of y, which defeats the whole point of bind variables.
It is most definitely not worth using dynamic SQL to force literalization of these values just for the purpose of a logging mechanism. You will create performance problems (hard-parse on every execution) and also litter the shared pool, eventually causing memory issues for the database. Most DBAs will push back hard against such an approach (and rightly so).
Most PL/SQL programmers rely on the error stack and call stack captured inside an exception handler. These are sent to a logging procedure that inserts them (inside an anonymous transaction) into a logging table, without the SQL itself. But the line numbers can be easily used to locate the SQL within you procedure/package, so you really aren't losing anything by not capturing the SQL.
Lastly, the method of using prev_sql_id is not very reliable. It is too easy to issue an extra SQL statement somewhere in the error handling or logging mechanism that pushes the offending SQL out of the prev_sql_id slot. If you don't have any exception handlers and the exception is raising to the client, you can use an after servererror on database system trigger which provides some pseudo-vars that permit capturing the offending SQL, but such a trigger only fires when an exception is thrown to the client. In PL/SQL programming, you typically handle exceptions within your code so the trigger would never fire. Not to mention, you are unlikely to be given the administer system trigger priv necessary for this - it's more of a DBA tool. Speaking of which, the prev_sql_id method also requires you to have the select any dictionary priv which not every developer will be given by the DBAs just because they ask. Access to v$sql is particularly sensitive because poorly written SQL using literals can expose bits of user data that you may not be intended to see. Considering this, DBAs might deny your grant request, and then you can't use v$sql/v$session.
I suggest using a normal exception handler and within that calling a logging procedure (that you write yourself) with parameters obtained from error-handling functions like dbms_utility.format_error_stack / .format_error_backtrace / .format_call_stack. Use that to manually find your SQL in your code later at debug-time, without attempting to capture and store the SQL at runtime. Also keep in mind that not all errors are from SQL. Many errors you might encounter are actually from PL/SQL and won't have an associated SQL at all. For even greater ease of debugging (at the cost of more coding), you can wrap every individual SQL statement or closely-related set of operations in its own exception handler. Then you can even name the operation/statement in your call to the logging procedure. I find that too much coding work, but it does give you a great deal of descriptive power if you need it.
If you need to know that y = 5, include an additional/optional parameter to your logging function that you can use for miscellaneous/detail info, and splice in the variable values you care about when you call the procedure from your exception handler. E.g. misc_info => 'vars: y = '||y||', x = '||x. The logging proc would write this to your log table along with timestamp and error stack info. But it is on you to code which vars you want to capture in your error handling.

This is something that is not recomended as already explained in "Paul W's" answer - it could get you more troubles than benefits.
But ...
Depending on the complexity of your sql commands to be logged and on number of bind variables used it is possible to get what you want but it could become quite complicated with complex query and multiple bind variables of different datatype.
Example of your last pl/sql block but with 2 bindings (Varchar and Number):
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
       x1   VARCHAR2(10);
       x2   NUMBER(6);
       y   VARCHAR2(50) := '5';
       z   NUMBER(6) := 5;
       m_sql   VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
       Select  y, z INTO x1, x2 FROM dual;

       --   checking the order of bind variables
       m_sql := dbms_lob.SubStr(sql_util.get_last_sqltext, 4000, 1);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(m_sql);

       -- replacing the bind variables with actual values
       m_sql := Replace(m_sql, ':B1', z);
       m_sql := Replace(m_sql, ':B2', '''' || y || '''');
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(m_sql);
END;
/

/*    R e s u l t :
SELECT :B2 , :B1 FROM DUAL      -- checking the order of bind variables
SELECT '5' , 5 FROM DUAL        -- actual values

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.    */

Example when working with cursor:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
   DECLARE
       m_dept_id      HR.departments.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE := 30;
       m_cnt   NUMBER(3) := 1;
       Cursor c IS 
            Select m_cnt "RN", m_dept_id "DEPT_ID", d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, e.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || e.LAST_NAME "EMPLOYEE"
            From   HR.departments d
            Inner Join HR.employees e ON(e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID)
            Where d.DEPARTMENT_ID = m_dept_id;
       m_set   c%ROWTYPE;
       m_sql   VARCHAR2(4000);
       m_sql_sequence  VARCHAR2(32000);
       
    BEGIN
       For m_set In c
       LOOP
          EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
          If m_cnt = 1 Then
            m_sql := sql_util.get_last_sqltext;
          End If;
          dbms_output.put_line(m_set.DEPARTMENT_NAME || '   ' || m_set.EMPLOYEE);
          m_sql_sequence := m_sql_sequence || m_cnt || '. ' || Replace(Replace(m_sql, ':B1', m_dept_id), ':B2', m_cnt) || Chr(10);
          
          m_cnt := m_cnt + 1;
       End Loop;
          dbms_output.put_line('----------------------');
          dbms_output.put_line(m_sql_sequence);
    END;
/

/*
Purchasing   Den Raphaely
Purchasing   Alexander Khoo
Purchasing   Shelli Baida
Purchasing   Sigal Tobias
Purchasing   Guy Himuro
Purchasing   Karen Colmenares
----------------------
1. SELECT 1 "RN", 30 "DEPT_ID", D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, E.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E.LAST_NAME "EMPLOYEE" FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS D INNER JOIN HR.EMPLOYEES E ON(E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID) WHERE D.DEPARTMENT_ID = 30 
2. SELECT 2 "RN", 30 "DEPT_ID", D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, E.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E.LAST_NAME "EMPLOYEE" FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS D INNER JOIN HR.EMPLOYEES E ON(E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID) WHERE D.DEPARTMENT_ID = 30 
3. SELECT 3 "RN", 30 "DEPT_ID", D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, E.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E.LAST_NAME "EMPLOYEE" FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS D INNER JOIN HR.EMPLOYEES E ON(E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID) WHERE D.DEPARTMENT_ID = 30 
4. SELECT 4 "RN", 30 "DEPT_ID", D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, E.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E.LAST_NAME "EMPLOYEE" FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS D INNER JOIN HR.EMPLOYEES E ON(E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID) WHERE D.DEPARTMENT_ID = 30 
5. SELECT 5 "RN", 30 "DEPT_ID", D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, E.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E.LAST_NAME "EMPLOYEE" FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS D INNER JOIN HR.EMPLOYEES E ON(E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID) WHERE D.DEPARTMENT_ID = 30 
6. SELECT 6 "RN", 30 "DEPT_ID", D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, E.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E.LAST_NAME "EMPLOYEE" FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS D INNER JOIN HR.EMPLOYEES E ON(E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID) WHERE D.DEPARTMENT_ID = 30 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.    */

